# Custom self closing tag in Tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, tinymce

Has anyone created custom self-closing non-html tags with attributes in tinymce?

I have tried the same on the lines of tinymce's **pagebreak** feature.
I went ahead and unminified the **plugin.min.js** associated with pagebreak.

I started tweaking the code by adding a pop-up to accept attributes for the custom tag.
I'm inserting my custom tag which is displayed to the user on UI as a logo image.
On clicking 'source code'(<>) from toolbar of tinymce, we must see only :

```
<mycustom attr1='value1' attr2='value2'/>
```

To the end user its meaning will only be an image, similar to how page break works.In page break, a tag is inserted in tinymce on viewing src, but actually on UI of tinymce editor we see dotted lines image.

```
----------------------
----------------------
```

This is achieved using 'Resolvename' function in **pagebreak** plugin.min.js

I am able to create the desired tag and pass attributes inside it, however when I click 'source code'(<>) plugin,
I see the tag:

```
<mycustom attr1='value1' attr2='value2'/>
```

in code view of tinymce, but on clicking 'OK', everything becomes empty!!

I read in many places that configuration in tinymce plugin using:
extended_valid_elements : "mycustom[*]" 
&
closed: /^(mycustom)$/
does the magic, but this did not work for me :(

I am not able to put screenshots because of low reputation:(.
Anybody has solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone? Please let me know if anyone is not able to understand the question.