# TinyMCE: How to enable self-closing tags? (custom tags)

Tags: tinymce

I can't get self-closing tags to work at all in the latest TinyMCE (6). This may be a duplicate of this question: [Custom self closing tag in Tinymce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31208784/custom-self-closing-tag-in-tinymce)

I'm trying to enter the tag `<x-button/>`, but TinyMCE is converting it to `<x-button></x-button>`.

I have in my config:

```
tinymce.init({
                selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
                skin: false,
                content_css: false,

                extended_valid_elements: 'x-*[*]',
                custom_elements : 'x-*[*]',
```

I've tried adding `schema: 'html5'`, `self_closing_elements : 'x-*'` and `self_closing_elements : 'x-*[*]', but these options seem to have no effect.

I found [this old fiddle](https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/ehhaab), but `editor.schema.getShortEndedElements()` no longer exists in TinyMCE 6.

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: I have found a work-around for now. I added `protect: [
     /\<x\-[^>]+\>/g,// ignore <x-*>
    ],`